# Problem 7.12 of 'Computability & Logic' (Boolos, Burgess, Jeffrey, 2007)

Tags: induction, recursion, computability

Can someone help with this Problem 7.12 from *Computability and Logic* 5th ed. (Boolos, Burgess & Jeffrey, 2007)?  I can't find the solution anywhere online.  Much appreciated.

If *f* and *g* are *n-* and (*n*+2)-place primitive recursive functions obtainable from initial functions (zero, successor, identity) by composition, without use of recursion,
we have shown in Proposition 7.24 [of the aforementioned book] that there are numbers *a* and *b* such that for $x_1, \ldots, x_n, y$, and *z*, we have:

$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x + a$, where *x* is the largest $x_1, \ldots, x_n$

$g(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y, z) = x + b$, where *x* is the largest $x_1, \ldots, x_n, y$ and *z*.

Show now that if $h = Pr[f,g]$, then there is a number *c* such that for all $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and *y* we have
$h(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y) < cx + c$, where *x* is the largest $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and *y*.

(N.b.  Proposition 7.24 demonstrated that it is impossible to obtain the sum or addition function from the basic functions (zero, successor, and identity) by composition, without using recursion.)